# How to get the values in the dictionary into the list form and then square them into list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, list-comparison

I have a dictionary of values in tuple form, how to get the values in list form.

I want to get values from the tuples and create new lists and create another 3 lists with squares from them.

```
dictionary={1:(1,2,3),2:(3,4,5),3:(6,7,8),4:(9,10,11),5:(12,13,14)}
s=list(d.values())
d=[item for t in s for item in t]
print(d)
```

I used list comprehension i got this output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Using list comprehension

Expected_output:

```
[1,3,6,9,12],
[2,4,7,10,13],
[3,5,8,11,14],
```

squares**2 output above three list :

```
[1,9,36,81,144],
[4,16,49,100,169],
[9,25,64,121,196]
```

Comment: Just do this: `d = [list(_) for _ in dictionary.values()]`.

Comment: Mmm, I suspect you're really looking for a 2D numpy array. Where does that dictionary come from?

Comment: @accdias That doesn't work. Look carefully at what's in the lists

Comment: Oh! I see now. My bad. You want to have the key appended as well.

Comment: No, they're going for a transposition

Comment: they just need to zip the sub lists.

Answer (score 2):

you can use zip to collect the index elements of each list together, then use list comprehension to square them

```py
dictionary={1:(1,2,3),2:(3,4,5),3:(6,7,8),4:(9,10,11),5:(12,13,14)}
list_vals = list(zip(*dictionary.values()))
squares = [[num ** 2 for num in nums] for nums in list_vals]
print(list_vals)
print(squares)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[(1, 3, 6, 9, 12), (2, 4, 7, 10, 13), (3, 5, 8, 11, 14)]
[[1, 9, 36, 81, 144], [4, 16, 49, 100, 169], [9, 25, 64, 121, 196]]
```

Thanks to comments from @roganjosh highlighting that the dict will only be assured to be ordered if the pythong version is 3.6 or higher. If your python version is less than that you would first need to sort the values by order of the keys. Below is an example.

```py
dictionary={2:(3,4,5),3:(6,7,8),4:(9,10,11),5:(12,13,14),1:(1,2,3)}
ordered_key_val = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda items: items[0])
list_vals = list(zip(*[val for key, val in ordered_key_val]))
squares = [[num ** 2 for num in nums] for nums in list_vals]
print(list_vals)
print(squares)
```

Comment: I agree that this is the way to go, but I think it depends on Python >= 3.6 to be sure that the ordering is correct?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Prior to 3.6, dictionaries, like `set`s, had no order. There is no guarantee that `dictionary={1:(1,2,3),2:(3,4,5),3:(6,7,8),4:(9,10,11),5:(12,13,14)}` will come out in the correct order in `list(zip(*dictionary.values()))`.

Comment: Ah yeah. I had mad an asunotion since the user didn't sort the list that either they are using 3.6 or greater or they don't care. For completeness when I am home I will update the example with a sorted version for pre 3.6

Comment: I think a caveat would be enough tbh. In _this case_ you could sort the keys and get the correct answer, but we're just fortunate that the keys are numerical and the output follows their numerical ordering. Otherwise, they'd probably need some key ordering before they created the dict :)

Answer (score 2):

Provided with a Dictionary

First take a empty list and assign it to a variable “l”

Using list comprehension separate the values and store that in a variable

Iterate the values and append the empty list “l”

Now iterate the “l” using index values i[o], i[1], i[2] and store in various variables respectively

Using map function square the variables and store the values and print them using the list of variables

```
x = {
    1:(1,2,3),
    2:(4,5,6),
    3:(7,8,9),
    4:(10,11,12),
    5:(13,14,15)
}
l = []
y = [i for i in x.values()]
for i in y:
    l.append(i)
print(l)

m = [i[0] for i in l]
n = [i[1] for i in l]
o = [i[2] for i in l]
m1 = map(lambda i:i**2, m)
n1 = map(lambda i:i**2, n)
o1 = map(lambda i:i**2, o)
print(m)
print(list(m1))
print(n)
print(list(n1))
print(o)
print(list(o1))
```

Comment: What about if the dictionary had 5000 items in it. Are you going to give each list a name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` to transpose the entire list once the values of the dictionary are obtained. You can use the below program

```
import numpy as np 
dictionary={1:(1,2,3),2:(3,4,5),3:(6,7,8),4:(9,10,11),5:(12,13,14)}
list_out= []
for i in dictionary.keys():
    list_out.append(dictionary[i])
tran_list =  np.transpose(list_out)
out_list = tran_list*tran_list
```

Output of this is:

```
>>> out_list
array([[  1,   9,  36,  81, 144],
       [  4,  16,  49, 100, 169],
       [  9,  25,  64, 121, 196]])
```

This is an array output! Anyway if you want it only in the list, ofcourse , you can play with it!

Comment: you can replace your for loop with a list comprehension of `list_out = [val for val in dictionary.values()]` but you can also just use zip from the python standard library rather then introducing a module that might not even be installed on the users system

Comment: Yes agreed, I am just presenting an other way doing it ! But your answer is more  affective!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
>>> temp = list(zip(*dictionary.values()))
>>> [list(i) for i in temp]
[[1, 3, 6, 9, 12], [2, 4, 7, 10, 13], [3, 5, 8, 11, 14]]
>>> [[i**2 for i in elem] for elem in temp]
[[1, 9, 36, 81, 144], [4, 16, 49, 100, 169], [9, 25, 64, 121, 196]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one dictionary here

```
d={1:(1,2,3),2:(4,5,6),3:(7,8,9),4:(10,11,12),5:(13,14,15)}
```

first I want to get  values in tuple  in three lists then I used list comprehension here The below code gives the tuple values in three lists

```
myList1 = [d [i][0] for i in (d.keys()) ]
print(myList1)
myList2 = [d [i][1] for i in (d.keys()) ]
print(myList2)
myList3 = [d [i][2] for i in (d.keys()) ]
print(myList3)
```

Here all the tuple values converted into list form

```
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13]
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14]
[3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Now I want to squares the elements in three lists here I Used lambda expression the below code squares the elements in the lists

```
a1= list(map(lambda x: x**2 ,myList1))
print(a1)
a2= list(map(lambda x: x**2 ,myList2))
print(a2)
a3= list(map(lambda x: x**2 ,myList3))
print(a3)
```

The output is:

```
[1, 16, 49, 100, 169]
[4, 25, 64, 121, 196]
[9, 36, 81, 144, 225]
```

Comment: What about if the dictionary had 5000 items in it. Are you going to give each list a name?

Comment: Then i will take one empty list  append elements into that list